# How to execute command line tasks on GAE and Cloud Run without SSH?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'd like to find a way to invoke CLI tasks in the production environment of App Engine Flex and Cloud Run, while staying in my local machine's terminal. By "CLI tasks" I mean `flask shell`, `rails console`, `rake`, `yarn run` and other application-specific command line tools.

Ideally, this would be a command that would start an instance with the same configuration as the actual production instance – same docker container, environment variables and so on – and remove it once I'm done.

I find the way [it is done on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#run-the-rails-console) the most immediate and useful:

> Heroku allows you to run commands in a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) - scripts and applications that only need to be executed when needed - using the heroku run command. Use this to launch a Rails console process attached to your local terminal for experimenting in your app’s environment

```rb
heroku run rails console
irb(main):001:0> puts 1+1
2
```

I could achieve similar results with the [App Engine debug mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance). To do that, I would SSH into the instance (or Cloud Run for that matter), pull up the bash shell with `docker exec -it gae /bin/sh` and then run the tasks. This has a bunch of downsides, and it is generally frowned upon, because it uses the same instance that serves the production traffic. It could potentially slow the webserver down or even halt it completely.

What would be the idiomatic GCP way to run a task in a separate instance similar to the heroku one-off dyno approach?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, there’s no way to run CLI commands in GAE Flex and Cloud Run in a production environment without accessing via SSH.

What you can do to make this possible in the future is to [request this feature](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=1162953).

Comment: Thank you, I've been getting this feeling too! Still, I wouldn't expect a feature request to be resolved in any feasible time. For the time being, I won't accept this answer – I'm hoping that with a bit of luck someone else will chime in with their workaround.